# Best approach for deploying multiple (Docker) container web app

Tags: docker, docker-compose, django

I have a fairly simple Django web app which I want to deploy somewhere.

I am keen to automate and simplify as much as possible and for that reason I am hoping to avoid having to deploy directly to one or more virtual servers, where I have to set everything up on the server myself, so was looking for a more managed/packaged approach.

I see that Docker offers great potential here, and so I have managed to get the web app working locally on a multiple container Docker implementation using docker-compose.

My Docker configuration includes 3 containers, one each for:

- The Django app and Gunicorn
- Nginx acting as a reverse proxy
- Postgresql database

I was (possibly naively) thinking that once I have a docker configuration working locally I would just be able to deploy this to the cloud with very little work, but when I have looked at how to actually do this I'm struggling to find how to do it.

Specifically:

- I looked at Digital Ocean's App offering which looked very promising but I can't see how to deploy a multiple container app on there. I use Digital Ocean for other projects and have had a good experience, which is why I chose them.
- I have done some research of other cloud providers but again not clear how to achieve exactly what I am trying to do.
- I know I could create my docker container on to a droplet or other VPS service, but I can't find a best practice way of doing that which minimises the amount of work I have to do outside Docker configuration, and as stated above, my ideal is to avoid this approach.

I have done a fair amount of searching but I haven't really found anything which exactly fits my case.

I realise this isn't rocket science so I'm just not looking in the right places or in the right way, so any suggestions, pointers or advice welcome.